# How to unload models

Tags: python, load

I was wondering how you would unload a model. I am using Panda3D and loading in .bam files as my models in the game. Would you do something like this:

```
ModelName = loader.loadModel(where the model is.bam)
ModelName = loader.unloadModel(where the model is.bam)
```

I want to unload a model and then load in another model in the same space if that helps any.

Comment: What is a "model" in this context? What do you mean by "load"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you described is (almost) correct.  When using `loadModel`, Panda3D will cache the model in memory, so that the model doesn't have to be reloaded from disk the next time you use `loadModel`.

If you wish to free up this memory because you no longer need this model, then you can use the `unloadModel` function with the return value you received from `loadModel`, which will release the model from the in-memory cache.  However, note that it will not actually remove any instances of that model that you have in the scene graph - you will still need to detach those.

If you want to remove a model from the scene graph, then simply calling `removeNode()` will do.  Orphaning a section of the scene graph like that will cause it to be garbage collected, given that you drop all references to it (and there are no circular references.